Do we have revolutionary tribunal records for Robespierre et al, 10 Thermidor An 2?
I'm interested in records of the French revolutionary tribunal. Do we have the transcript of, for example, Robespierre's trial before the revolutionary tribunal during the Thermidorian reaction? Do such records exist at all?

Robespierre was put on trial, according to most secondary sources, on 10 Thermidor and promptly executed. The trial transcripts exist for a number of revolutionary tribunal proceedings: eg Danton, Charlotte de Corday. I have been unable to find the correct one for Robespierre, Saint-Just, and compatriots.
The inventory for the public prosecutor on the French national archives for W 111 to 154 (by Danis Habib) isn't entirely helpful. Some documents are clearly there from 10 thermidor but I am unclear as to whether they are the correct ones.

W 120 piece 163 seems to be a letter from Herman to the public prosecutor on the decrees against Robespierre et al
W 136 piece 23 seems to be a summary of judgements rendered by the tribunal with 14 names but I am unclear as to whether this is a transcript or not
W 149 piece 135 is a letter from Boulland to Tallien of the same day (not sure why it's in the public prosecutor's files) but that's clearly not a transcript

The reason why I asked this question is because I am unsure as to whether the records exist. Searches are unrevealing because they keep returning irrelevant depictions (especially paintings and engravings) of or secondary sources on the events of those days. I am also unclear as to whether the public prosecutor archives are even the correct place to be looking: the prosecutor and the tribunals were formally separate and might have had different final dispositions for records regardless.
Are there trial transcripts for Robespierre, Saint-Just, et al on 10 thermidor an II? If so, where are they?
Edit. Are they in serie W 79–80? W 434?

Okay I'm very sure now that the correct set of documents is W 434 dossier 975. But there doesn't seem to be an index I can find anywhere for the pieces of that document. From secondary sources, specifically Wallon History of the Revolutionary Tribunal vol 5 pp 250ff, it seems:

piece 3 is "Convention says: they're outlaws; kill them"
piece 4 is "Convention says: kill them now"
piece 39 is the judgement

Which raises the question as to what pieces 1–2 and 5–38 are. And whether there are any pieces beyond 39.

What have you tried so far? Any preliminary research? A simple search gives many links, can you please narrow down your search and clarify what exactly you need?

I've been unable to find the trial transcript for Robespierre specifically, held on 10 Thermidor. I've found trial transcripts for Louis, Marie Antoinette, even references to the transcript for Danton. Standard collections of primary sources don't seem to include it, as they republish mostly essays and decrees. Collections for Thermidor itself seem mostly to relate to elements such as the speeches given before the convention rather than the trials on 10 Therm of Robespierre, Saint-Just, et al.

The inventory for the public prosecutor (boxes 111 to 154) on the French national archives doesn't seem entirely revelatory. There are some documents there for 10 Thermidor but I'm not sure whether they are the correct ones, such as W 136 item 23 Etat de jugements rendu par le tribunal revolutionnaire le 10 thermidor (suivent 14 noms). That sounds like a summary and not a transcript.

Thanks for the edit and clarification, voted to reopen.

@ifly6,  The French National Library’s digital platform, Gallica, has digitized many historical documents from the Reign of Terror. This includes some trial records.  Notable: Marie Antoinette, Georges Danton, and general records of the Revolutionary Tribunal’s activities.
